# How to include a JVM in JAR file if Java is not installed on user machine?

Tags: java, jar, include, jvm

Maybe the question sounds a bit strange...
I would like to distribute my Java application.
I know how to generate a jar file, but it only includes my classes.
What if the user does not have java installed on its computer ?

So what I would like to know is how to include the JVM in my JAR file. Or find the equivalent correct way of doing this.
I found almost nothing about this so I'm probably asking the wrong question...

Many thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't include the JVM in the JAR file. You can, however, put the JRE in your distribution next to the JAR file - assuming you know what platform (OS, processor) the distribution is intended for. On how to do that, you can read [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jrereadme-182762.html).

Answer (score 2):

You do not know anything about client computer architecture, you can't provide common JVM for all types of computers (it depends on OS and processor).

It is not possible, you can easily distribute application, but not virtual machine itself.

Comment: Oh ! Makes a lot of sense now.
So you basically have to ask the user to install Java on its computer.
Ok thank you very much for this fast answer :)

Comment: You can, however, write installation scripts for each target platform that installs java if it is not already installed.

Answer (score 1):

You may use some application packager like [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) that includes a test for installed Java on the host and if needed forward user to Java download/install page.

Your use case is covered by the [readme](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jre-7-readme-430162.html) file. You can and you are allowed to distribute the Java Runtime along your application (jar). It is a question how to start then your app accordingly to the OS.